# flutter intl 0.17.0-nullsafety.2 package initializeDateFormatting

Tags: flutter, dart, intl

i need some help because im going crazy. I just want to format date to my locale (should be it-IT).

In flutter app i putted in pubspec.yaml the intl package with the new nullsafety feature:

```
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.17.0-nullsafety.2
```

looking into the documentation it says:

<< Note that before doing any DateTime formatting for a particular locale, you must load the appropriate data by calling: >>

```
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
...
initializeDateFormatting('de_DE', null).then(formatDates);
```

(https://pub.dev/packages/intl/versions/0.17.0-nullsafety.2)

so, just to try, i did:

```
initializeDateFormatting('it-IT', null).then((value) => {print('intl ok')});
```

but the dart nullsafety doesnt want a null parameter, and it says "The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'."

Any suggestion?

Comment: 1. `intl` 0.17.0 is out, so there should be no reason to continue using the 0.17.0-nullsafety.2 pre-release version. (Unfortunately, the documentation is still wrong though.) 2. This is unrelated to your reported problem, but `(value) => {print(...)}` is a function that returns a `Set<void>`.  You either want `(value) => print(...)` or `(value) { print(...); }`. 3. Have you tried passing an empty string (`''`) instead of `null`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Here the answers:
1. right, now im using intl 0.17.0 but the problem is still there
2. yes i had to do `(value) => print(...)` but it doesnt matter
3. yes i have tried, but then i had a runtime error:  `Cannot open file, path = 'symbols/it-IT.json'`

Comment: See https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/417.  Are you using `import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';`?

Answer (score 0):

**Thread: flutter intl 0.17.0 package initializeDateFormatting.**

Same problem here, did you solve the issue?
I tried upgrading intl to ^0.18.0, but in my pubspec.yaml I am using

```
  flutter_localizations: # Add this line
    sdk: flutter
```

so, my project is coupled with intl 0.17.0. I realize this when I tried the [flutter pub get] command and got this message:

```
Running "flutter pub get" in expenses...                        
**Because expenses depends on flutter_localizations from sdk which depends on intl 0.17.0, intl 0.17.0 is required.**
So, because expenses depends on intl ^0.18.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because expenses depends on intl ^0.18.0, version solving failed.)
```

I also made a lab with only dart and not flutter, and intl works as expected:
https://gist.github.com/ejyanezp/994c49f15bb2ce3fd4c3d84ed37ca198

So is a compatibility issue between *flutter_localizations* and *intl*.

**Conclusion**: i will go for a workaround and wait the final solution from the authors of both libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the similar issue where `initializeDateFormatting(localeName, null)` was imported from `'package:intl/date_symbol_data_file.dart'` and it requires `filePath` in arguments or if you import it from `'package:intl/date_symbol_data_http_request.dart'` you have to pass `url` in second argument that is required.

Intl package has `initializeDateFormatting()` declared in different three files if you only want to pass locale you should consider it importing from `date_symbol_data_local.dart`

```
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart'

final String localeName = Intl.canonicalizedLocale('en_US');

try {
  await initializeDateFormatting(localeName, null);
} catch (error, stackTrace) {
  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The error message you're seeing is because the `initializeDateFormatting` function expects a non-null String parameter to specify the locale, but you're passing null. To fix this issue, you should pass the locale as a string, like this:

```
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';

void main() async {
  await initializeDateFormatting('it_IT', null);
  print('intl ok');
}
```

Here, I've used `'it_IT'` as the locale identifier for Italian (Italy). Make sure to use an underscore instead of a hyphen when specifying the locale. This should allow you to initialize date formatting for the Italian locale in your Flutter app.